# What is wrong with this simple html/PHP form? It works when testing locally but fails on the actual server

Tags: php, html

I want to add a “send message” form to an existing website. I found this tutorial:

[PHP Contact Form](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-contact-form/)

I reviewed the code in the tutorial, learned how it worked, and then programmed it. I got it up and running and it passed all my tests, running it locally on my PC.  It works perfectly.

Then I put it on a server as part of an existing website. It failed. A click on the Submit button clears the screen and the form is lost to view. No error messages. Nothing.

Both XAMPP and the actual server are running PHP version 8.1.12.

It fails on this line of PHP code:  header('Location: contact.php', true, 303);

I have spent considerable time debugging this, learning more about PHP, following advice found here on Stack Overflow, and I read the PHP documentation about function header(). I took took two LinkedIn Learning classes on PHP.  I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Then I reduced the problem to this simple code, making it as simple as possible, a form with a submit button only. It has the same problem as the complete form.

Here is my test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Contact</title>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
$request_method = strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
if ($request_method === 'GET'){
?><form action="for_stack_overflow.php" method="post">
<button type="submit">Send Message</button>
</form>
<?php
}
elseif ($request_method === 'POST'){
header('Location: for_stack_overflow.php', true, 303);
exit; 
}
?></html>
```

This simple html/php code has the same problem as my full up form:  upon clicking the submit button, the screen is cleared and the form, only a single button, is gone. The form does not work.

I removed all indentation on purpose, because I learned that a common problem is that unseen whitespace causes failures of the PHP function header().

This program (and my complete form) each:

1. work perfectly when testing it locally on my PC;
2. fail when running on the real server, on my website hosting account.

I have exhausted all my remedies to solve this problem.

What is wrong? What could be wrong? What is it that I don’t understand?

Comment: Did you try just doing this `header('Location: for_stack_overflow.php');`

Comment: What is the file name of the code you provided? Here you check `if` the incoming request `is POST` but then you use `header()`? `header()` doesn't send any output to `for_stack_overflow.php`, it is merely utilized as a redirect to prevent a double submit *after* processing POST. Also, terrible tutorial, doesn't even include header.php anywhere! LOL!

Comment: Enable error logging in your local PHP. Add a trigger_error() call on top of your file to verify PHP error logging does work (test). Then enable error logging on your server and do the same test. For debugging purposes raise error_reporting to the highest level (E_ALL). It is very likely you find messages in the error log of your server that you don't see locally. Those are the interesting ones and they should be with filename and line.

Comment: To answer your questions:  1. Yes (did not fix the problem), 2. "for_stack_overflow.php." Also, your advice about error logging is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `header()` and `session_start()` calls to before the HTML output.

```
<?php session_start();
...
?>
<!doctype html>
...
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
> sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

> Note:
>
> ```
> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputting anything to the browser.
> ```